# How do I yield a character from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, stack-overflow

I would like to have a callable function (because iter() needs it) that gives me a sequential character from a string.

This function has stalled my pc, I had to reset the computer.

```
cnt=0
def myfunc():
    global cnt
    cnt+=1
    yield "abczdef"[cnt]

list(iter(myfunc,'z'))
```

Comment: What do you expect to be the result of `list(iter(myfunc, 'z'))`?

Comment: I expect ['a','b']  - a list that includes 'a','b'. The iter() sentinel has stopped on the 'z'.

Comment: It's in no way going to generate `['a','b']`. At the very least the result should be `['b','c']` (you incremented `cnt` before using it as an index)

Comment: Maybe this is a dif quest but, why my code cause pc freeze?

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string as an iterable directly:

```
def characters(string, sentinel):
    for c in string:
        if c == sentinel:
            break
        yield c
```

```
>>> list(characters('abczdef', 'z'))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

A more functional approach, like you had in mind, would be:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def characters(string, sentinel):
    return takewhile(lambda c: c != sentinel, string))
```

Using the `iter(callable, sentinel)` form can be made to work, too, but I find the other solutions more readable:

```
def characters(string, sentinel):
    chars = iter(string)
    return iter(lambda: next(chars), sentinel)
```

---

#### Why your attempt freezes the computer

> ```
> list(iter(myfunc,'z'))
> ```

is equivalent to:

```
result = []
while True:
    x = myfunc()
    if x == 'z':
        break
    result.append(x)
```

If you look at what happens when you call `myfunc()`:

```
>>> myfunc()
<generator object myfunc at 0x7f1e0f1020a0>
>>> myfunc()
<generator object myfunc at 0x7f1e0f1020f8>
>>> myfunc()
<generator object myfunc at 0x7f1e0f1020a0>
```

you see that it creates a new generator object each time it is called.

Obviously none of these objects is equal to `'z'`, so this creates an infinite loop.

Comment: That seems to work, but I was trying to use iter() with a sentinel.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to have pointed me in the right direction. I was looking at the itertools module and the takewhile function doc has code I could mod.  ->       def myf2():
    for x in "abzdef":
        yield x

Answer (score 0):

With the syntax `iter(f, sentinel)`, the first argument `f` must be a callable object that **`return`s the result**, not `yield`-ing it.

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter):

> If the second argument, *sentinel*, is given, then *object* must be a callable object. The iterator created in this case will call *object* with no arguments for each call to its `__next__()` method;

So, this is the answer you're looking for:

```py
cnt=0

def myfunc():
    global cnt
    cnt += 1
    return "abczdef"[cnt]
#   ^^^^^^

list(iter(myfunc, 'z'))
```

Which, as expected, gives `['b', 'c']` as the result (note on the absence of `'a'`: you incremented `cnt` before using it as the string index, so you're never accessing `"abczdef"[0]`):

```py
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> cnt=0
>>> def myfunc():
...     global cnt
...     cnt += 1
...     return "abczdef"[cnt]
...
>>> list(iter(myfunc, 'z'))
['b', 'c']
>>>
```